# android enable 'settings' permissions

Tags: android

I'm writing some automation testing for my app,
On my emulator is there a way to enable settings permissions (permissions that requires the user to go to device settings and enable them) 
like usage state, accessibility services, notifications from ADB? (like 'adb shell pm grant')

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any APIs that can to that, but if you're using `UIAutomator` it is pretty easy to achieve. If you're using `Espresso`, you need to add `UIAutomator` (`Espresso` is for single app testing, while `UiAutomator is cross-app testing`) and this will give you the possibility to access the `Settings` app.

Answer (score 0):

Using `adb` the closest you could get is opening the Application settings.

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS
```

Otherwise `UIAutomator` would be the way to automate this.